# how to capture the exit time stamp when case owner changes from a specific queue

Tags: case

how to capture the exit time stamp when case owner changes from a specific queue.

I have created a workflow to capture the entry time and for exit time i put the criteria to formula evaluates to true.

I need the formula to test the old value of caseowner.